# cant start mysql using xampp v3.2.1

Tags: mysql, xampp

I tried alot things but then again. Need help on this. I tried to delete the idbata1 file and no effect on it.

Please... I checked mysql_error.log and this is the error:

```
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-12-13 10:03:41 1afc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Binlog end
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
```

2014-12-13 10:03:41 4444 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete